# ATTACH DATABASE gives "database is already in use" on Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In a native app project both on iOS and android we encountered issues with **sqlite3** on android. We want to open two databases and **attach** one database to the second database via [ATTACH DATABASE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) (sql-command).

### What we do:

1. open sqlite3 database "user.db" (final native filepath on android
   device is '/data/user/0/com.company.app/databases/user.db', we use **android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase**)
2. open sqlite3 database "system.db"
3. attach the user-database to the system database:

on the SQLiteDatabase-Instance for system.db-database, we execute

```
ATTACH DATABASE '/data/user/0/com.company.app/databases/user.db' AS dbUser
```

### Result:

This gives the following error:

> Database dbUser is already in use (code 1)

The same sql-statement on sqlite3 for iOS is working fine without any errors.

For the sake of completeness. The databases are opened with the following statement:

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

SQLiteDatabase mydb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbfile.getAbsolutePath(), null, openFlags);
```

Asking google for this kind of error message gives lots of sites stating, that it is not allowed to use TEMP as database alias. Since we use "dbUser" and not TEMP, there should be another reason. We can't figure out right now.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to open a database that is to be attached; the ATTACH statement already opens it.

Anyway, the error "Database *xxx* is already in use" indicates that some database is already attached with that specific name.

The problem with your code is that it is executed twice.

Answer (score 2):

Frequently this happen when attach command execute several times,
you can use DETACH command

```
DETACH DATABASE 'database_name';
```

and then ATTACH database again or ATTACH with new name like:

```
ATTACH DATABASE file_name AS new_database_name;
```

remember when ATTACH with new name, other connection to the database still open.

Answer (score -1):

Without being much involved, isn't "attaching something you do before opening a database. I've been using regular sql express versions and I believe I cannot attach or detach while open. Attaching might be handled differently on iOS and android which might cause issue on one

Comment: In fact, the documentation doesn't mention anything on this topic. We made it work on android some months ago. The error is completely new to us now. Some minor versions later.,...